# AG Grid: unable to use Column Tool Panel as package 'ag-grid-enterprise' is not presented

Tags: ag-grid-react

Code is messy, I cannot paste it.

The warning: `AG Grid: unable to use Column Tool Panel as package 'ag-grid-enterprise' is not presented...`

I need only clue to look up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to your application to enable the enterprise features.

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise`;
```

You can see more about how to add it from the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/licensing/#via-grid-packages)